# Filtering an unbound datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, arcobjects

I have an unbound `DataGridView` that is being populated by pulling attributes from selected features in ArcMap as well as user inputs from text boxes. I have the following code below that loops through the `DataGridView` and makes rows invisible, based on the value of a combo-box matching a cell in a column.

```
private void comboBoxName_SelectionChangeCommitted(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string TextVar;
    TextVar = comboBoxName.Text;
    checkBoxShowAllRows.Checked = false;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow df in this.dataGridList.Rows)
    {
        if (dataGridList.Rows[df.Index].Cells[5].Value.ToString() == (TextVar))
        {
            dataGridList.Rows[df.Index].Visible = true;
        }
        else
        {
            dataGridList.Rows[df.Index].Visible = false;
        }
    }
}
```

That works well. However, I have a date column that will be populated on a new row by reading the date in the row above and adding the amount of days that a user puts into a text box. My issue is that even if I filter out rows with the code above, the date code will still look at the invisible row and use that row above. Is there a way to avoid invisible rows in my index? I want to be able to filter different values but not get rid of them. Would the `.Visible` method of filtering not be preferred in this case?

Comment: Off-topic re: code quality: I think you might be able to replace `dataGridList.Rows[df.Index]` with simply `df` inside your `foreach` loop.

Comment: It's difficult to understand exactly what you need help with: You've shown us some code that works, but when it comes to the code that *doesn't* work, you've not included it in your question. Your problem statement, _"My issue is that even if I filter out rows with the code above, the date code will still look at the invisible row and use that row above. Is there a way to avoid invisible rows in my index?"_ is simply too vague. Can you please provide more detail and the code that doesn't work as desired?